# Looking for documentation about custom readable codes

Tags: qr-code, barcode

Do any of you know what to call these codes? My best guess is custom QR codes. Facebook (messenger) and Snapchat has their own QR codes and I want to look into how to create these - well my own of course!

Does anyone here have anything I could research? A mane? Some documentation or just something?

Have a wonderful day!

Comment: I you're trying to do it programatically, there are [several QR code generating APIs](https://www.google.com/search?q=qr+code+api). These can often store quite a bit of data, including text and URLs.

Comment: Well, if you look at facebook messenger code and the snapcodes, they are not QR codes, but some kind of scanable custom codes, kind of like QR codes. And I want to create my own kind, if it makes any sense?

Comment: There are plenty of alternative 2D barcodes to QR that are designed to ISO specifications, including Data Matrix, Aztec, and PDF417. Their encoding and reading methods vary by code. You absolutely could design your on codex like Snapchat and Facebook have, but I imagine it would involve a fair deal of image recognition and a consistent scan pattern. A common characteristic of 2D and 3D barcodes are a specific start marker, and many often utilize an endpoint or boundary marker as well

Answer (score 0):

Those QR codes are either using the "Frame QR" format or taking advantage the error correction bits to recover the damage done by placing a logo in the middle of the barcode.  QR codes have 4 levels of error correction that can be added to the code to allow a partially damaged barcode to still be readable.

For more information:  https://www.qrcode.com/en/codes/